# VS code не выдает подсказки (частично)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

День добрый! Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Подсказки html, css, js работаю как положено. Но, получая элементы со страницы:

```
let hisAge = document.querySelectorAll('.m-age');
hisAge.style......
```

После ввода hisAge.st(подсказки style и других свойств нету). Точно также если ввести hisAge.style.back[backgroundColor](подсказки свойств отсутствуют). Надеюсь на помощь! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) возвращает массив элементов. Свойство `style` есть у [элемента](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). Элемент возвращает, например, функция [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: Это я в курсе. Но даже так hisAge[0].style.backgroundColor - style b bgc не подсвечиваются в подсказках. Для меня это не критично, но хотелось бы что бы они работали.